# How do I restore the default Postscript printer?

Tags: printing

I did a *Reset printing system...*, thinking it would remove all printers I installed. I didn't think it would remove everything, including the default Postscript printer.

**EDIT:**

I'm on a MacBook Pro mid-2014, on OS X 10.10.3.

1. I went to *Printers & Scanners*
2. I right-click on the printer list
3. Then, I chose *Reset printing system...*

I know I didn't delete "Postscript" itself, just the configured Postscript printer target. Still, I want to bring it back, since I didn't intend to delete it.

Here's a screenshot of the action I'm referring to, although I just found this and it's not a screenshot from my machine.

http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2011/09/14/ResetPrintSystem.png
[image]

Comment: how did you do it, on what system, what model

Comment: Postscript is not a actual printer, it is a software, and I doubt you have deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

1. Go to *Printers & Scanners*
2. Click on "+" to add a new printer
3. Click on *IP*

   1. Address: localhost
   2. Protocol: Line Printer Daemon - LPD
   3. Name: PostScript
   4. Use: Generic PostScript Printer